# Weighted shuffle of dictionary by weight of value

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has elements to sort as keys and their weights / probabilities as values.

I would like to get a sorted list of keys using the values as probability to be the next element chosen.

Example:

```
l = {6: 5859, 7: 61636, 2: 53317}

# Example output 1
output1 = [7,2,6]
# Example output 2
output2 = [2,7,6]
```

I researched a bit and found the sort function redefining it and multiplying random() with the weight itself, but I do not get the syntax to run.
So my "pseudo code" python solution is:

```
from random import random
l.sort(key = lambda element: random() * element.value())
```

Of course, a dictionary does not have a sort function and element.value() does not work, but this is how I think it could work with better syntax.

Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort an iterable which is not a list, either convert it to a list first, or call `sorted` on it directly.

For instance, if `d` is a `dict`, then you can sort its keys using:

- `a = sorted(d.keys())`; or
- `a = list(d); a.sort()`.

Since you need both the keys and the values, you should work on `d.items()` rather than on `d.keys()`. Then, if the `key` function you pass to `sorted` is defined as `lambda x: ...`, you can refer to the dict key as `x[0]` and the dict value as `x[1]`.

I seem to understand that a higher weight should increase the probability that a number will come first. In that case, you should use optional argument `reverse=True` of `sorted`, to sort in decreasing order rather than in increasing order.

With all this in mind, fixing your code:

```py
import random

d = {6: 5859, 7: 61636, 2: 53317}

a = [k for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: random.uniform(0, x[1]), reverse=True)]

print(a)
# [7, 2, 6]
```